# Can a chrome extension page opened in the browser communicate with the background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

One of my extension html page, when opened in the browser needs to communicate with the background script. I have tried approach mentioned [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) but not able to send a message from the page to the background. How can I do it? I cannot have content script on pages that start with something like `chrome-extension://namhfjepbaaecpmpgehfppgnhhgaflne/content/web/viewer.html` and hence not able to use traditional message passing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link mentioned in your question is for normal web-pages outside of the extension package.

If the displayed html file belongs to your extension package you can use all of the chrome APIs permitted by manifest.json in the page script files.

For example, to send a message to the background/event page use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage):

- options.js, linked from options.html

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: "Hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
  });
  ```
- background/event page

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (message.text == "Hello") {
          sendResponse({text: "Got it"});
      }
  });
  ```

Alternatively you can access the background page directly:

- persistent background page

  ```js
  chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().someGlobalFunction()
  ```
- [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(bg) {
      bg.someGlobalFunction();
  });
  ```

As for content scripts, you can add them directly by manually referencing in your html file:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="mycontentscript.js"></script>
..............
```